# How do I reference a web service in another project using a ScriptManager?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I have a web application project and a web service application project. I'm using ASP.Net AJAX and I want to reference a service called Tickets.asmx from the web service project and call it with JavaScript. (I'm referencing it [or trying to] in a ScriptManager on the page)

I've done this before with the web service being part of the asp.net web application, but not with it in a different project. No matter what I do I keep getting [namespace] undefined javascript errors.

What could I be doing wrong? I've even tried putting the full path to the service in the ScriptManager (something like http://localhost:4080/Tickets.asmx)

Comment: You didn't say what problem you're having...

Comment: "No matter what I do I keep getting [namespace] undefined javascript errors."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have determined that this is not possible. JavaScript cannot make calls to another domain, so ASP.Net AJAX doesn't support external web services at all.